# Automation Studio Activity (Journey Entry) not appearing. (Permissions?)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automationstudio, automation, activity

I am reviewing some activities in our SFMC instance that some previous coworkers built. In one automation activity, I am seeing an activity I can't find. I can't find the "Journey Entry" activity in Automation Studio Activities section. See screenshot.

I can't find this activity in the Activities section. Could it be a permissions thing? Or does it pop up if something else is activated/configured first?

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Thank you,
N

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a journey with a Data Extension with automation set as entry source, it will add this activity automatically to your automation.

> When you select Automation, the journey evaluates contact records when
> your chosen automation completes.

You cannot add it manually from Automation Studio.

Doc: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_schedule_a_data_extension_entry_source.htm&language=en_US&type=5

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj!

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer as accepted if it helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. I never saw the option to drag "Journey Entry" as an Automation Activity to drag over to step 2. I had luck with setting up the Automation Filter (step 1), then set up my Journey in Journey Builder to use that Automation as the Schedule. Once I **activated the Journey** and **activated the automation**, the Journey entry audience popped into the Automation automatically as Step 2. It never showed up as an option to drag over from the Activities section of the Automation. I hope this helps...